# Return Status after merging the data in laravel raw query

Tags: laravel

I have a query that picking a date and then the data will generate and the sum of **sales_onhand_deposits.total** has a two status/is_verified 0 and 1

for example i'm picking the date from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31 if **sales_onhand_deposits.total** has a status of 0 it will return a pending ,
and if **sales_onhand_deposits.total** all the status is 1 it will return an approved

```
$result = $this->sales_on_hand->where(function($query) use($request, $dateStart, $dateStart2){
                    $query->whereBetween('sales_onhands.created_at', [$dateStart, $dateStart2]);
                    if($request->has('branch') && $request->branch != ""){
                        $query->where('branch_id', $request->branch);
                    }
                })->join('sales_onhand_deposits','sales_onhands.id','=','sales_onhand_deposits.sales_onhand_id'
                )->select(
                    DB::raw(
                        '
                        IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhands.cash_on_hand), 0) AS cash_onhands,
                        IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhands.gc_onhand), 0) AS gc_onhands,
                        IFNULL(SUM(sales_onhand_deposits.total), 0) AS total_deposit,  
                        IFNULL(SUM(case when sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 0 then sales_onhand_deposits.total else 0 end), 0) AS total_pending_deposit,  
                        IFNULL(SUM(case when sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 1 then sales_onhand_deposits.total else 0 end), 0) AS total_approve_deposit
        
                        '
                    )
            )->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can check count of all records with the conditional count of records where is_verified is 1, if these both count matches then it means all for the records are with is_verified  1 and final result will be considered as approved

```
DB::raw(
    ' ....,
    IF(COUNT(*) = SUM(case when sales_onhand_deposits.is_verified = 1 then 1 else 0 end), "approved", "pending") AS sale_status
    '
)
```